# Draw trail of circles with mouseDragged

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I am trying to write a program that draws a line of circles with mouseDragged, like MS paint does. I have successfully gotten my program to draw a circle when I click. I have also been successful in getting my program to draw a circle when I drag the mouse; however, this doesn't leave a line of circles behind wherever I dragged. It simply drags the same circle around. I am trying to get my program to leave a trail of circles behind where I am dragging but I am pretty confused on why my program wont do so.

```
package assignment_11;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.*;


public class Canvas extends JComponent implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{

private int x, x1;
private int y, y1;

public Canvas() {
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    addMouseListener(this);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //creates new JFrame, sets Exit On Close, sets visible
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.add(new Canvas());
    window.pack();
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
}

public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(640,480);
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println(arg0);
    x = arg0.getX();
    y = arg0.getY();
    repaint();

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println(arg0);

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println(arg0);

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println(arg0);

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println(arg0);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.fillOval(x, y, 10, 10);
    g.fillOval(x1, y1, 10, 10);
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println(arg0);
    x1 = arg0.getX();
    y1 = arg0.getY();
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
    System.out.println(arg0);
}


}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `"I also HAVE read many of the so called "duplicate" questions and in light of this still wanted help with MY code, as I have approached the problem differently (granted it may not be the best way to approach it)."` -- it's not that your way is "not the best way", it's the *wrong* way. Follow the advice given to you by MadProgrammer below and you won't go wrong. I have to admit to being surprised and dismayed that you re-asked the question without even leaving a comment to mad's answer about anything that confuses you, as if you didn't read it or care about it.

Comment: I'm simply approaching the problem with the tools I have been taught so far in my course. The course has not covered ArrayLists so I am confident there is a way to solve this problem in a different way than the solution provided here. I do not have time to teach myself ArrayLists, which is a completely new topic to me, and I do not want to simply copy his code. In addition, I was not "re-asking the question," I was asking a different question that is an extension of this one. I didn't respond because I solved the problem covered by this question on my own without using MP's techniques.

Comment: Regardless -- don't ignore the answers given, and then ask a new question. You've no comment to Mad's answer, none, and yet you re-asked the question, which looked to him and to all of us that you completely ignored all the effort that he put in to answering you, when you re-asked the question. Again, this will demotivate anyone from answering any future questions that you might ask, since no one wants their volunteer efforts totally ignored. At least up-vote and accept his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Painting is destructive.  That is, every time `paintComponent` is called, you are expected to repaint the entire state of the component.

This raises the issue - you need some way to store the state you want to paint every time `paintComponent` is called.

For this, a simple `ArrayList` would do the job nicely.  It would allow you to store all the points you're interested and allow you to repaint them each time `paintComponent` is called, for example...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Canvas extends JComponent implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private List<Point> points;

    public Canvas() {
        points = new ArrayList<>(25);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater((new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame window = new JFrame();
                window.add(new Canvas());
                window.pack();
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                window.setVisible(true);
            }
        }));
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(640, 480);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(arg0);
        points.add(arg0.getPoint());
        repaint();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(arg0);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(arg0);

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(arg0);

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(arg0);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        for (Point p : points) {
            g.fillOval(p.x, p.y, 10, 10);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(arg0);
        points.add(arg0.getPoint());
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(arg0);
    }

}
```

Now, as the complexity of your problem grows, you could instead store "shapes" in the `List` which have some kind of notion of how to paint themselves, allowing to add in more complex shapes

You should also have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to gain a better understand of how painting in Swing actually works

Comment: (1+) but, for the OP, I wouldn't call the class `Canvas`. There is an AWT class with that name so it gets confusing. Class names should be more descriptive.

Comment: @camickr No argument